# Using a CKAsset with SDWebImage for the first time - cannot convert Data to URL

Tags: swift, image, cloudkit, sdwebimage

I have an array of `CKRecords` in an array. Using a table, I am looking to use `SDWedImage` to act as a cache for the one CKAsset/Image in my Records.

**Code I have tried:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "restaurantcell") as? RestaurantTableCell

    cell?.dealsicon.layer.cornerRadius = 3

    let restaurant: CKRecord = restaurantArray[indexPath.row]

    let asset = restaurant.value(forKey: "Picture") as! CKAsset

    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: asset.fileURL)    

    cell?.restaurantImage.sd_setImage(with: data)

    return cell!
}
```

However, with the use of the sd in code, I receive the below error,

> Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'URL'?.

How would I go about fixing this error?

Is there an alternative to my constant `data` that trys a URL instead of data?

Comment: If the error occur on this piece `.sd_setImage(with: data)`, then Try `cell?.restaurantImage.sd_setImage(with: asset.fileURL)`

Comment: It worked perfectly, lol :D. Thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome :) I also answered below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error occur on this piece `.sd_setImage(with: data)`, then not need to get `Data` from `URL`. Because, `sd_setImage` parameter is `URL`.

**Try Below Code,**

```
cell?.restaurantImage.sd_setImage(with: asset.fileURL)
```